# Function calling HTML5 canvas routines doesn't exit as expected

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I have encountered a unknown to me anomaly in Javascript coding: I completely don't know why, but there are some functions that a compiler just won't return from, and it just 'sits' there, even though after the '}' bracket there are next lines of code.

Look at following example - I have a main function which contains calls to functions like initShaders(), initBuffers() or drawScene() one after another. And the inside of troublesome initShaders() looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <canvas id = 'c' width = '500' height = '500'></canvas>
    <script src ='js/webgl-utils.js'></script>
    <script src ='js/webgl-debug.js'></script>

<!-- MAIN WEBGL SCRIPT -->
    <script>
        var gl;
        var offset;
        function initWebGL() {
            // Create space and try to create context for WebGL
            var c = document.getElementById('c');
            gl = null;
            gl = c.getContext('experimental-webgl');

            // Check if browser supports WebGL
            if (!gl) {
                alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.");
            }
            // Continue only if WebGL is available and working
            else {
                // Javascript console debug tool
                gl = WebGLDebugUtils.makeDebugContext(gl, throwOnGLError, logAndValidate);

                offset = [1, 1];
                // Choose background color
                gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

                initShaders();

                initBuffers();

                drawScene();
            }
        }

        var program;
        function initShaders() {
            program = gl.createProgram();

            // Call this function when loadProgram function will load shaders
            function initProgram(loadedProgram) {
                program = loadedProgram;
                gl.useProgram(program);

                /*-- Specify ATTRIBUTES locations --*/
                // Specify locations of variables passed to shader program
                program.vertexPosAttrib = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexPosition');
                // Enable this attribute as an array
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPosAttrib);
                program.offsetUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uOffset');

                // Set the format of an in-data
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPosAttrib, vertexPosBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0 ,0);

                /*-- Specify UNIFORMS locations --*/

                // TODO exit this function...
            };

            // Load the shaders from the file
            loadProgram('shaders/vshader-00.txt', 'shaders/fshader-00.txt', program, initProgram);  
        }

        var vertexPosBuffer;
        function initBuffers() {
            vertexPosBuffer = generateQuad();
        }

        function drawScene() {
            // Clear the scene before rendering
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            /*-- Pass UNIFORMS to shader program --*/
            gl.uniform2f(program.offsetUniform, offset[0], offset[1]);

            // Draw some triangles with predefined amount of vertices
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexPosBuffer.numItems);  
        }

        initWebGL();

    </script>
</html>
```

The thing is that after the command 'gl.vertexAttribPointer(...)' it just do nothing, while it should exit this function, go after loadProgram function and keep going. It works fine if I put initBuffers() at the end of loadProgram() and then call drawScene() inside innitBuffers(). But this is just unpractical. What is the cause of this issue?

EDIT: PS program variable has been globally declared earlier.

EDIT2: Pasted the whole code from the main file for better clarity.

Comment: Did you look at the console for error messages?

Comment: Yup, and there are no error messages. It only says it stopped at the end of loadProgram function (looks like it don't know what to do at the end of it). As I said in a main post, if I specify at the end of that function the next function that it should automatically proceed to, it will go further. I bet this has something to do with Javascript required coding structure which I don't acknowledged yet.

Comment: And we have no idea what that function does ?

Comment: `initProgram` is called _by_ `loadProgram`, it doesn't run after it.

Comment: I'm guessing that `loadProgram` does something asynchronous, and `initProgram` is used as a callback when the async action completes.

Comment: loadProgram() is not a Javascript standard function, it is defined elsewhere.  What libraries or other scripts are you using?

Comment: So how should I exit that function and return to main function in which the next step is initBuffers()? @Paul - I'm using WebGL and some Kronos's debugging tools to list all calls of functions to Debugging Console, but I believe that this has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Searching `var`s from your code didn't match. Are you sure `program` is what you expect in every function?

Comment: You may want to put a var in front of 'program' in the 2 occasions its assigned. Otherwise they will share the same (global) variable which is not what you want. Also you may want to read up on closures.

Comment: I have declared program as a global variable earlier, and yes, that is completely proper way of using it. Whole code works when I specify next steps at the end of loadProgram function. The problem is that I don't know how to say to the compiler to just exit it, and go back to the main function where it ended (so after calling initShaders function) (or I should rather say, I don't know why it don't know that it should go there in the next step)

Comment: There is a library called [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) that some people use to create cleaner looking code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, most things are non-blocking. the `loadProgram` call will return immediately. However by then the program is not loaded yet. When it is loaded, the callback `initProgram` will be called.

JavaScript is event driven and therefore the control flow may be a bit harder to follow.

If this is running in a browser, you may want to start a timer at the end of initProgram which should then call your 'main' function when it is fired. This mechanism would be somewhat similar to what is happening with `loadProgram` which calls `initShaders` when it is done loading the program.

Comment: The problem is that initShaders() is in the middle of the main() function, so calling it again would not be the best idea. If there is no another way of getting back to the spot where it ended in that case, I may create a next main2() function with the rest of the code from main(), and then call main2() at the end of initProgram()

Comment: Yes. If you don't call them 'main' it probably doesn't feel that badly anymore. This is how things are done in JavaScript - everything non-blocking.